# Slightly change the Bresenham/midpoint circle algorithm for nicer results

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry, bresenham

I do have two ways of creating a filled circle via bresenham/midpoint algorithm.
But the second way looks far better than the first way.

[image: bresenham/midpoint]

I want to create a result like the second one, but with the way of the first
one. I want to do it with the first way because I need a correct formula for calculating distances which is this one at the moment:

```
function calcDistance (pos,pos2,range){
    var x1 = pos.hasOwnProperty('x') ? pos.x : pos[0],
        y1 = pos.hasOwnProperty('y') ? pos.y : pos[1],
        x2 = pos2.hasOwnProperty('x') ? pos2.x : pos2[0],
        y2 = pos2.hasOwnProperty('y') ? pos2.y : pos2[1];
    return Math.pow((x1-x2),2) + Math.pow((y1-y2),2) - Math.pow(range, 2)
};
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ru55fa3/9/) . The first approach was taken from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midpoint_circle_algorithm) the second from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30585171/3143953)

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: @BrentWashburne I want to create a result like the second one, but with the first approach.

Comment: What does your `calcDistance` function have to do with drawing the circle?  It is not mentioned in either approach.

Comment: @BrentWashburne did you see the jsfiddle? there you can see how i use it.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of drawing points when the distance is `<= 0`, draw points when the distance is `<= radius*radius*zoom`:

EDIT: applied a scaling factor of `(8.0/radius)`

```
function drawCircle(x0, y0, radius){
  var range = radius*radius*zoom*(8.0/radius);    // calculate the range once
  for(var x = 0; x < imageWidth/zoom; x++){
    for(var y = 0; y < imageHeight/zoom; y++){
      if(calcDistance([x0,y0],[x*zoom,y*zoom],radius*zoom) <= range){
        context.fillRect(x*zoom,y*zoom,zoom,zoom);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: thank you, but your solution only works for a few radii. f.e. 2-6 does not work, as well as it does not with 9, 11,..

Comment: thanks but i need it for all possible radii, at least for 1-30

Comment: That's expanding the scope of the question slightly, and now it's a math problem to calculate the appropriate range.  I leave that part up to you.